# Запрос в таблице по fk mysql

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица users и таблице branch_users

```
SELECT * FROM `user`
INNER JOIN branch_users ON branch_users.user_id = user.id
```

Мне нужно выбрать всех пользователей из таблицы user, которых нет в таблице branch_users. То есть, если user.id=1 есть в таблице branch_users - его не выводить, если не - выводить.

Не получается сделать запрос, есть варианты?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так

```
SELECT * 
FROM `user`
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                  FROM `branch_users`
                  WHERE branch_users.`user_id` = user.`id` 
                  )
```

[NOT EXISTS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html) - Оператор возвращает результат: 1 (TRUE), если результат подзапроса не содержит ни одной строки, и 0 (FALSE), если результат подзапроса непустой

Comment: Спасибо, как-то не приходилось таким оператором пользоваться, буду знать))