# Выборка с условием отсутствия в другой таблице

Tags: mysql, база-данных

Есть две таблицы posts и reposts, известны переменная $idTape (например 15).
Задача: Найти пост, которые не публиковался ранее.

```
 SELECT * FROM posts WHERE category = 'Тест' LIMIT 1
```

Но чтобы в таблице reposts не было записи где posts.id_post = reposts.id_post и reposts.id_tape = $idTape

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Запрос в таблице по fk mysql](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/589135/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81-%d0%b2-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be-fk-mysql)

Comment: Пока не пробовал. Я воспользовался ответом @Akina - он работает.

Comment: Какое, на ваш взгляд, лучшее решение? @Akina или через оператор NOT EXISTS?

Comment: Если надо проверить одну запись - not exists, если записей много, left join может быть быстрее. А в 50% случаев думаю вообще одинаково будет

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT posts.* 
FROM      posts 
LEFT JOIN reposts  
       ON posts.id_post = reposts.id_post 
      AND reposts.id_tape = $idTape
WHERE reposts.id_post IS NULL
  AND posts.category = 'Тест' 
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Вечером я не работник, но по моему вот Ваше решение:

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE category = 'Тест' LIMIT 1 AND posts.id_post NOT IN (select id_post FROM reposts WHERE id_tape = $idTape)
```

У меня сейчас нет возможности проверить запрос, поэтому в нем возможны синтаксические ошибки, но в качестве стартовой точки надеюсь, что Вам это поможет