# Помогите с sql запросом one-to-many

Tags: php, sql

Есть таблица support_tickets и таблица ticket messages

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

связазь one-to-many. Нужен запрос который будет искать те тикеты, у которых не существует ticket_messages

Пока есть такой вариант

```
SELECT * FROM support_tickets where id not in (SELECT distinct ticket_id from ticket_message)
```

Есть ли альтернативные варианты, которые будет работать быстрее?

Comment: Почему вы решили что у вас медленно и вам надо быстрее?

Comment: `Есть таблица tickets и таблица ticket messages` - а что за таблица  `support_tickets` тогда?

Comment: Уточните вопрос. В скриншотах не видно `ticket_messages`. Таблица `support_tickets` в запросе неожиданна... Что с чем связать-то надо

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Запрос в таблице по fk mysql](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/589135/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81-%d0%b2-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be-fk-mysql)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT st.* 
FROM support_tickets st
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT id 
                  FROM ticket_message tm
                  WHERE st.id = tm.ticket_id
);
```

`NOT EXIST` - возвращает значение 1 (TRUE), если результат подзапроса не содержит ни одной строки в подзапросе, и значение 0 (FALSE), если подзапрос что-то содержит

А вот быстрее ли такой запрос, чем ваш с `IN` может подсказать разве что `EXPLAIN`

Comment: То есть Вы так видите _тикеты, у которых не существует ticket_messages_

Comment: @DNS а у вас какое-то другое видение? Поделитесь?

Comment: Запись у которой  нет таблицы... Да, я вижу это по-другому...

Comment: @DNS ну если вы это интерпретировали как "нет таблицы" - то что тут можно поделать?

Comment: Не интерпретировал, а понял буквально... Интерпретацию увидел...

Comment: @DNS Если бы было как вы подумали, то оно должно было бы звучать "not exists ticket_message". А тут "где (where) не существует (not exists) выборки из таблицы (select * from ....) с таким то id"

Comment: Я понимаю, пятница, вечер. Но что с юмором-то? Все я понимаю, просто троллю ситуацию. В надежде хоть немного позитива внести в эту ветку...

Answer (score 1):

Можно еще попробовать так:

```
SELECT st.* 
FROM support_tickets st
LEFT JOIN ticket_message tm ON tm.ticket_id = st.ticket_id
WHERE tm.ticket_id IS NULL
```

Выбор варианта - на основе анализа плана выполнения.

**UPDATE**

SQL сервер для вашего запроса и варианта Олега строит идентичный план выполнения. Для моего варианта план немного отличается - использует SORT вместо DISTINCT SORT и LEFT JOIN вместо RIGHT ANTI SEMI JOIN, что приводит к изменению стоимости с 0.085 до 0.087 - т.е. чуть хуже, но это на моих тестовых данных; на других данных результат может быть иной.

**UPDATE 2**

И действительно - в первом случае у меня в таблице ticket_message было много меньше записей, чем в support_ticket. В другом случае, когда в таблице ticket_message записей много больше (это более реалистичный вариант, не правда ли?), мой запрос дает практически такой же результат, что запрос Олега (стоимость 0.14 и 0.15, соответственно), а ваш - почти вдвое хуже (0.25).