# SQL запрос для обьединения двух таблиц с учетом пустых полей

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Дорогие программисты!
Имеется две таблицы: таблица заказов и таблица клиентов.
У этих таблиц имеется общее поле email.
Задача состоит в том, чтобы выгрузить кол-во людей, которые не сделали ни одного заказа.

В данном запросе происходит выгрузка емейлов без учета пустых полей, с помощью которых как раз можно и посчитать делал ли заказ клиент или нет.

Как сделать запрос так, чтобы он учитывал пустые поля в таблице пользователи?
Т.к. я буду совмещать всех пользователей и заказы и смотреть кто из них делал заказ.

```
SELECT `orders`.email AS emailstOrders, 
    `clients`.email AS emailClient
FROM  `orders`, `clients`
WHERE `orders`.emailstOrders = `clients`.emailClient
```

Comment: вместо `,` используйте left join и проверяйте поле на NULL

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Запрос в таблице по fk mysql](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/589135/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81-%d0%b2-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be-fk-mysql)

Comment: Приведите структуру таблиц, или хотя бы укажите, есть ли в `clients` уникальный ID, и есть ли на него ссылка в `orders`

Answer (score 0):

Используйте тип соединения `left join`, который оставит null, что собственно и будет означать, что клиент не сделал ни одного заказа (если я правильно понял структуру вашей БД):

```
SELECT o.email AS emailstOrders, 
    c.email AS emailClient
FROM  `clients` c left join `orders` o on c.email = o.email
WHERE o.email is null
```

Comment: Прошу прощения, подправил названия таблиц

Comment: @DmitriyAndreevich подправил ответ

Comment: Жуть... а за синтаксисом кто будет следить? присвоил таблицам алиасы - а в выходном наборе почему имена? И зачем в  выходном наборе `orders.email`, который, согласно условию отбора, `is null`?

Comment: @Akina ага, поправил элиасы. ТС сам вывел их в своих попытках, значит хочет посмотреть на null'ы в отдельном столбце

Comment: @Akina, Я хочу сделать так, чтобы в таблице клиенты были и нуллы и имейлы, чтобы вычислить кто делал заказ, а кто не делал, так как таблицу клиенты я сравниваю с таблицей заказы, и по нулам определаю делал ли заказ конкретный клиент

Comment: @DmitriyAndreevich Офигеть логика... а просто одним запросом получить активных, а другим пассивных, или одним запросом полный список, но с полем "покупал/не покупал" - не? обязательно самому по полупереваренным данным определять?

Comment: @Akina, так тоже хотел, но нет конкретного поля, в котором было бы видно делал заказ или нет:( поэтому приходится так извращаться(